# How to update state of original page after ModalBottomSheet pop?

Tags: flutter

I have setup a floatingActionButton:

```
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
    shape:
        RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
    onPressed: () async {
      _showAddDrinkPanel();
    },
  ),

  void _showAddDrinkPanel() async {
    showModalBottomSheet (
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(25.0))),
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return ChooseDrinkForm();
        });
  }
```

choose_drink_form.dart

On this page it gets the users input on drink amount and then saves it to the database (sqflite) the button to submit is:

```
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          _submitLog();
          Navigator.pop(context);
        });
```

Now the problem is that when the Modal pops back the page hasn't updated to reflect the amount the user just added in the Modal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling setState in onpressed method you can call setState method in showModalBottomSheet's then method which may solve your issue.

Like in following code.

```
 void _showAddDrinkPanel() async {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(25.0))),
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return Text("data"); 
        }).then((value) {
      setState(() {});    // setState addded
    });
  }
```